# Check zone assignment from Windows Explorer in Windows 8/Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-explorer

I'm trying to determine whether a particular folder is assigned to the Intranet zone.  On previous versions of Windows, I could look in the status bar at the bottom of a Windows Explorer window, like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find the same information on Windows Server 2012, and having trouble.  I know I can get the zone of a web site by loading it in IE and looking at the page's properties.  But I can't use this to get the zone of a folder -- the folder opens right up in Windows Explorer (where I can't find the zone info).

So -- is the zone information accessible from within Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too had this same frustration so I did quite a bit of digging awhile back and found something interesting.

Read this first:  http://web.archive.org/web/20151106085041/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2011/08/01/what-happened-to-the-zone-information-on-the-status-bar-in-ie9.aspx

I know that my link references IE 9 instead of Windows Explorer, but every version since 9 up to 11 has had the status bar degraded (my words) so that it doesn't show Zone Information.  This was done to save CPU cycles and increase performance and page loads.  This change was also applied to Windows Explorer in Windows 8/Server 2012 and on as well and you won't find it on Server 2012 Windows Explorer.

You can still find the IE zone by going to File > Properties in IE but not in WE.

Comment: I know I can get the zone info from IE properties.  But the problem I have is that when I try to open this location in IE, it automatically pops it open in Windows Explorer instead.  Is there a way to force IE to load a network share in IE itself, rather than deferring it to Windows Explorer?

Comment: Tools > Internet Options > Security Zone would allow you to set the intended target as a zone that you could load in IE.  But please see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448319/ie11-unable-to-open-windows-unc-file-path

Comment: How'd this work for ya?

Comment: Well -- I was finally able to determine the zone by putting a dummy html page inside the folder, loading that page in IE, and getting the properties.  Just seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: I completely agree.